# Test case for checking blob response in React Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to test this `blobdownload` function which returns a promise of API data in blob format.

```
async function blobdownload(url){
  const data = await fetchData(url);
  data.then(response => {
      if(response.status===200)
      return response.blob()
    }
  throw new Error()
  );  
}

blowdownload().then(blob => callback(blob,'PDF'))
```

fetchData(url) returns a promise.

callback(blob) is a callback function that will download the blob in the required format.

```
it('should mock correctly', async () => {
const mock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
   json: () => {
      data: {}
   }
});

const data = await blobdownload(mock);
expect(data).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I have tried this way but I am getting exception if I passed this mock data.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: What is the context for this snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to mock blob data as well as the status in order to pass the below test cases.

```
it('should mock correctly', async () => {
  const mock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    status: 200,
    blob: () => "Data"
  });

 const data = await blobdownload(mock);
 expect(data).toEqual("Data");
});
```